# Parent Child Table Based on Indentation

Tags: excel, vba

We have a lot of these type of projects in the pipeline and picked one of the more complex projects for you savvy VBA folks to solve.  We are looking to fill a lot of 'data' roles in our company, so we're excited see who the experts are out on this forum and possibly work together on future projects!

Requirements:
We're trying to create a Parent (Column C) to Child (Column D) to Alias (Column E) based on the indented hierarchy in Column B via Macro.
We were able to get Column C, D, E the way it is via Macro by making a copy of Column B into Column A and filtering on the Green vs No Fill and applying the correct formulas in Columns C, D, E.
The only thing left to do is to populate Column C with the remainder of the Correct Parents.

**CHALLENGE**
If you take a look at the full hierarchy at the bottom on the thread, you'll notice the varying indent levels that need to re-use a parent from above.

For example, row 126 would need to be defined as Parent 'Bank' from above.
Row 312 would need to be defined as Parent 'ASSETS' from above.

[image: Example]

For example,

cell C9 should be ASSETS
C10 should be Current Assets
C11 should be Bank
C12 should be Cash
C14 should be Cash
C18 should be Cash
so on so forth.

Does anyone have any ideas how to automate rest of the Parents via Macro?
Here's the current Macro that will produce Columns C,D,E based on Column B.

```
Sub RunAll()
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Range("A6").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Range("A6").Activate
    With Application.FindFormat.Font
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Subscript = False
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5296274
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True, _
        FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        
        Columns("A:D").Select
    Range("A7").Activate
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$D").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterNoFill
    Range("F1").Select

'Update Account Length
            
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-3],7)"
    '                                      X
    Range("G1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]"
    Range("F1:G1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$D").AutoFilter Field:=1
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$D").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(146, 208, 80 _
        ), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    Range("F1").Select
    
'Update Account Length+3

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(RC[-3],1))),RIGHT(RC[-3],LEN(RC[-3])-10),RC[-3])"
    '                                                                                      X
    Range("F1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$D").AutoFilter Field:=1
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$D").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterNoFill
    Range("E4").Select
    
'Update Account Length

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(AND(LEN(RC[1])=7,LEN(R[-1]C)=0),R[-1]C[1],IF(AND(LEN(RC[1])=7,LEN(R[1]C[1])=7),R[-1]C,R[-1]C))"
        '                   X                                            X               X
    Range("E4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$D").AutoFilter Field:=1
End Sub
```

UPDATE:
We added a Function in a Module to get the Indent Levels to see if we can leverage this to build out the Parent information.  Wanted to share this in case it may help someone come up with a solution.

You'll need to use the following formula for the Function to work properly.

=PROFEXIndentLevel(B8)

```
Function PROFEXIndentLevel(Cell As Range)
    'This function returns the indentation of a cell content

    Application.Volatile
    'With "Application.Volatile" you can make sure, that the function will be recalculated once the worksheet is recalculated
'for example, when you press F9 (Windows) or press enter in a cell

    PROFEXIndentLevel = Cell.IndentLevel
    'Return the IndentLevel

End Function
```

[image]

Full Hierarchy (Row #, Hierarchy, Indent Level)
[image]

Comment: If anyone wants the Excel file, please let me know.

Comment: It looks like for obtaining a parent, simple iteration from the above cells should do the job: 1. Get intendation level of a child object. 2. Iterate over the cells above the child cell until previous value level is found. So, if the child cell level is 5, then search for level 4.

Comment: I posted the full hierarchy at the bottom of the thread.  Please take a look at row 137.  How would it get the parent based on this indent level?  The indent level jumps around and re-used throughout the hierarchy.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is that we have to deal with the word "Total" in the beginning: it can be easily excluded if needed or "Total' word with the space after it can be removed to get the child name and its parent.

Comment: Is the indenting white space?

Comment: Yes.  White space before the string.

Comment: If the space symbol is used for indentation then why `Cell.IndentLevel` is used in `PROFEXIndentLevel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: *I'm posting my code as an answer as I'm not sure that multiline code could be posted in comments.*

The code is based on my comments above. Assumptions I made, I added as comments to the code:

```
Public Function GetParent(ByRef rng As Range) As String
  Const TTL As String = "Total "
  Const sep As String = " - " ' number-name separator
  Const firstRow As Long = 1 ' first row above which no data we are looking for
  Dim i As Long, currIndentLevel As Integer, n As Integer
  
  Application.Volatile
  
  currIndentLevel = PROFEXIndentLevel(rng)
  
  If currIndentLevel = 0 Then ' I guess, zero indentation level has no parents
    GetParent = ""
  ElseIf UCase(Left(rng.Value, Len(TTL))) = UCase(TTL) Then ' I guess, TOTAL has no parents (just used for TOTAL info)
    GetParent = ""
  Else
    i = 1
    Do While rng.Row - i >= firstRow
      If PROFEXIndentLevel(rng.Offset(-i, 0)) = currIndentLevel - 1 Then
        GetParent = rng.Offset(-i, 0).Value
        ' remove leading number
        n = InStr(GetParent, sep)
        If n > 0 Then GetParent = Mid(GetParent, n + Len(sep))
        Exit Do
      End If
      i = i + 1
    Loop
  End If
End Function
```

[image: My test]

Comment: Nice one, ENIAC.  Your assumptions were all correct and the solution worked like a charm without any issues!

Comment: @eniac loving the dark background in vbe. How did you set that please?

Comment: @qharr, **Tools** > **Options** > **Editor Format**